# Best way to store lots of unstructured data in a multithreaded iOS app with memory constraints?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I've gone around in circles with this problem in my app over several months. I've tried many home-brewed solutions and will explain what I have working here, but I hope someone can suggest a better solution I missed.

The basic problem is this: I have (potentially) thousands of Items that need to be accessed by my app at any time. A NSMutableDictionary would normally be my first approach to represent each item, since each Item might have anywhere from a few to hundreds of properties. But the rest of the requirements make things hairy:

1. Each Item might be read from or written to by any thread
2. Each Item needs to be stored to disk so that it can be retrieved between sessions
3. There are (potentially) so many items (and so much data) that to have them ALL in memory at once could cause memory issues

I wanted to use CoreData because Apple likes it so much, but I ran into lots of problems. Each Item does not have a definitive structure, so there is no good way to structure the data model. Furthermore, querying for data caused the single .sqlite file to act as a bottleneck, meaning that the wait times (lag) got absurd very quickly when many threads were trying to retrieve items at once.

I have a working solution, but it has problems. Here's a chunk of the code, and I'll explain what it does below

```
- (NSObject*) getValue:(NSString*)key {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if(!_cached_obj) { // private variable in this object
            _cached_obj = [self loadFromDisk]; // simply loads the NSDictionary from a file
        }
        _last_access = time(nil);//don't release for a while
        return [_cached_obj valueForKey:key];
    }
}
- (void) setValue:(NSObject*)value forKey:(NSString*)key {
    @synchronized(self) {
        [self getValue:key];//ensures the cache is active
        [_cached_obj setValue:value forKey:key];
        _needs_save = true;
    }
}
- (void) clean {
    if(!_cached_obj)
        return;
    @synchronized(self) {
        if(_needs_save)
        {
            [self writeToFile];//writes the cache obj to a file
            _needs_save = NO;
        }

        NSTimeInterval elapsed = time(nil) - _last_access;
        if(elapsed > 20)
        {
            [_cached_obj release];
            _cached_obj = nil;
        }
    }
}
```

- When I need the data from an Item, the getValue function is called. It tries to use a cached object (NSMutableDictionary). If the cached object is NULL, it loads the object from disk before returning
- The setValue function works as expected, but also sets a save flag
- The "clean" function is run on a 10s timer by a background thread. This takes care of saving the Item to disk and uncaching data in order to conserve memory.

What I don't like about my approach is that there's a LOT of waiting on semaphores based upon my use of @synchronized. Occasionally, this also means that the main thread is blocking while it waits for disk read/writes, which is painful.

Is there a better data structure or storage mechanism I'm missing?

Thanks!

---

EDIT: More information:
The speed an which the "getValue" function returns is also of very high importance, even if it is not blocking the main thread. For example, consider the scenario where I am searching through 10k items on the background thread. I will need to get a single value from each of the 10k objects once. With my current mechanism, it works, but loading each non-cached object up from the disk is time consuming and it ends up taking ~20 sec on my iPhone 4. I understand that this might be just "a price I have to pay." But, perhaps storing the data in smaller chunks could help? Eg, don't store an entire item as a dictionary, but as a collection of distinct objects.

Comment: Can you explain the data that you are dealing with a bit more in-depth? What is your use case? Why are dealing with so many items that have variable or dynamic structures?

Comment: Have you considered only running `clean` in response to a memory warning as a way of decreasing cache misses?  You might also get value from indexing the "single value" that you want in the background but that would depend on how frequently things change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you profiled your app and the profiles show that the @synchronize blocks are the biggest performance bottleneck. Right?

Well, I'm not overly surprised: you read and write your files while holding the mutex as you pointed out. Moreover, you allow only one thread at the same time, while you could easily allow many readers or one writer to access your cache.

Identified locking operations:

- get value -> get value in cache, get value on disk if not in cache, put value in cache
- set value -> get value in cache, get value on disk if not in cache, put value in cache, put new value in cache
- clean -> save cache, empty cache

So then, the basic operations are:

- get value in cache
- get value on disk
- put a value in cache
- save cache
- empty cache

It's pretty easy to determine the concurrency of these simple operations, and then to rework your locks to ensure everything works nicely with each other.

You can allow many reader or one writer to access the cache. One thread can read (or write) on disk, without having to lock the cache. The value read from disk will be set in cache as a writer later on. So one read-write lock for the cache, and a mutex for the file. The set value sequence is also a bit puzzling. I do not see the point of reading the old value from the file to replace it immediately. If you need the cache data structures to be ready, just ensure they are without triggering a file operation.

All of this can also be implemented using GCD, avoiding most of the locks if not all.

There is plenty of room to reduce the collisions without introducing a lot of complexity nor changing the app threading model. GCD offer even more opportunities I think, but you'll have to think in terms of queues and operations instead of threads, which is not always easy at first sight.

I will not say reworking the locks will be enough, you may also have to improve how the data are read and saved to disk, but start with the locks. You may be surprised.